# Unable to add Sections with header/footer to a List in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I've been tinkering for a bit with SwiftUI but some of the errors the compiler shows are a bit inexpressive and difficult to understand as I'm getting started.

I'm building a list with the latest Xcode versions with sections in the following way,

```
public struct DatasetView: View {

    public init() {}

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = DatasetViewModel()

    public var body: some View {

        List(viewModel.directories) { folder in
            Section(header: Text("Section")) { // <-- Error here
                Text(folder.path)
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Dataset")
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)

    }
}
```

The error produced is

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Section' with an argument list of type '(header: Text, @escaping () -> ())'
```

I've searched in the documentation and checked blogposts that use the same syntax but I'm lost here. What's missing/wrong?

*EDIT*: Added the `DatasetViewModel`

```
public class DatasetViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var directories: [Directory] = []

    init() {
        search()
    }

    func search() {

        let docsPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
        let urls = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: nil, subdirectory: "dataset/train")

        var aux: [Directory] = []

        urls?.forEach({
            aux.append(Directory(path: $0.pathComponents.last! ))
            print($0.pathComponents.last)
        })

        aux.sort(by: < )

        directories = aux
    }
}
```

```
public struct Directory: Identifiable, Comparable {
    public static func < (lhs: Directory, rhs: Directory) -> Bool {
        return lhs.path < rhs.path
    }

    public var id = UUID()
    public var path: String
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `DatasetViewModel`?

Comment: My bad, added it!

Comment: And `Directory` if possible. I'm assuming it conforms to `Identifiable`?

Comment: Yes, it does. My problem comes in the `Section`part of the View I think

Comment: Using the code for your view, view model and the Directory struct, I don't get any errors when I compile and run with Xcode 11.3 targeting iOS 13.3. Do you definitely still have errors after you clean & rebuild the project? What Xcode version & platform version are you targeting?

Comment: yep, i agree to Seb, no error here for 13.1, 13.2, 13.3 and 13.0.....

Comment: I'm getting the error in a Swift Playground created on Xcode with the iOS template, shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: I can’t replicate your error on my end either using the latest version of Catalina and Xcode.

Comment: May it be the case that you have some class or struct in your code that is named "Section"? That is what I had and I got a similar error message. If you do not want to change the name of your class or struct, you can prepend the swiftUI section as SwiftUI.Section (or at least use this for testing).